# Creating a ContextMenu with available web applications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contextmenu

I'm developing an application that needs to open a web browser in order to show a web page. In addition, the user can open using my own application, so I need to display all the available web browsers and the then handle the option the user chose.
So far, I open the context menu, but I don't know how to populate it with the items I need.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    Log.d("WebOff","Creating ContextMenu");
    menu.setHeaderTitle("MyTitle");
    menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.MyIcon);
    menu.add("MyItem");
}
```

What I want to achieve looks something
 like [this](http://www.docscannerapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/chooseSendApp.png), but with the browsers installed in the device and my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    ComponentName caller = new ComponentName(Activity.this, Activity.class);

    menu.addIntentOptions(0, 0, 0,caller, null, i, Menu.FLAG_APPEND_TO_GROUP,null) ;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but I couldn't find a way to handle the event after that.

Comment: you cant , only menus added using menu.add can be handled, the above will directly launch the app

Comment: @candiani: This code will populate the menu with events that will automatically fire. Quoting the docs, "For each of the generated items setIntent(Intent) is called to associate the appropriate Intent with the item; this means the activity will automatically be started for you without having to do anything else."

Answer (score 0):

The image you point to is not a context menu. Rather, it is the result of calling `startActivity()` with the `Intent` you want to use (e.g., `ACTION_VIEW` on your Web page URL).

Normally, the user will only have one browser, and therefore `startActivity()` will not display a chooser dialog as is shown in your image. If the user does have more than one browser, *and* the user has not chosen a default browser, normally the chooser dialog will appear.

You state that "I need to display all the available web browsers". Bear in mind that if the user has already chosen a default browser, they may not appreciate your forcing them to make another choice. That being said, you can call `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(viewIntent, "some caption"))`, where `viewIntent` is the `Intent` you ordinarily would have just used with `startActivity()` and `"some caption"` is what you want to have displayed at the top of the dialog (where the image has the poorly-written "Choose application where want file/files to be sent").

You further state that you want to "then handle the option the user chose". That is not possible using the standard chooser mechanism -- Android handles the choice for you. If you *really* need to "handle the option the user chose", you will need to create your own chooser dialog, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to get the data to populate that dialog.

Comment: That is completely true, but I need to do it for an assessment, so I can't ignore what I was asked.

Comment: @candiani: Then follow the instructions in the last paragraph of my answer.